# Android Tabs Fragments

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-fragments

My tabs fragments doesnt seems to show anything. I know there must be something missing in my codes. Could someone please help me? Below are my attempt.

Modified after the suggestion by UgglyNoodle

Problems : My fragment Tab is not showing anything.

MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        //mFragment = new AppleFragment();

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Apple")
                .setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apple);

        actionBar.addTab(tab);


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
         if (mFragment == null) {
                mFragment = new AppleFragment();
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
            } else {
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.detach(mFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

AppleFragment.java

```
    public class AppleFragment extends SherlockListFragment{


        static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
        // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
        static final String KEY_DESC = "description";



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        }


        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });


            setListAdapter(adapter);    


        }
}
```

XMLParser.java

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

Logcat :

```
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab/in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:45)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.AppleFragment.onCreate(AppleFragment.java:50)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:834)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1136)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1943)
10-05 16:24:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(19244):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using an `ArrayListFragment` anywhere. And why does it extend `ListActivity` rather than `ListFragment`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Fragments. Could you please guide me how it is done?Thanks UgglyNoodle

Comment: I'm trying to use both ListActivity and Fragments . ListActivity are needed for my ListAdapter to work. I'm having trouble on how to combine both together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need your `AppleFragment` class. Instead, you can have your `MainActivity` to implement `TabListener`. Here is some quick code which gives you the basic idea, but I have not tested it and it will need some fixing.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Apple")
                .setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apple);

        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = new ArrayListFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.content, mFragment, "some_tag");
    } else {
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.detach(mFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

When you have multiple tabs, you will need to keep track of the multiple fragments, and attach and detach the right ones according to the tab selected.

Finally, your `ArrayListFragment` should extend `ListFragment`, and you will still be able to use `setListAdapter()` and so on.

[This page](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragmentsactionbar) has a pretty good example, although it is a little more complicated than what I have suggested.

Comment: Hello UgglyNoodle, I've edited my codes, but it seems that my listadapter needs extend Listadapter to work. Please correct me

Comment: For the context to pass to your `ListAdapter`, just use `getActivity()`.

Comment: Thanks UgglyNoodle, Just changed it to getActivity() . But i'm still not getting any results shown on my fragments. Please check on my codes. I've debugged the codes, it doesnt goes into my AppleFragment class.

Comment: Don't set your list adapter in `onCreateView()`, because the list hasn't been created yet. Do all of that stuff in `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: I've created onActivityCreated(). Please check on my codes. Something is still missing i guess. I'm still not getting any results yet. Please help UgglyNoodle

Comment: Take a look at my edited code. The resource `R.layout.main` should be your activity layout, and `R.id.content` should be a container in your layout where you want the fragment to go.

Comment: Hm.. I'm getting an exception when i debug on this line "String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);" I'm not sure whats wrong, i've pasted my logcat. Please assist me UgglyNoodle

Comment: Okay, then that's an entirely separate issue and has nothing to do with tabs or fragments. You should probably start a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask a new question. Thanks alot.. !